# Layout using vh does not scale with zoom

Tags: css, scale, viewport, viewport-units

I've tried to create a login form using ONLY `vh` sizes.
Doing this, in the hopes that the form, in all, would scale accordingly to the viewport.

It doesn't! For some reason zooming in, creates a blank space that keeps getting bigger the more you zoom, between the input fields and the text below.

http://jsfiddle.net/TnY3L/

The fiddle isn't very well made, just copied it from my project.
But you can see what's wrong - and that's what counts.

Anyone have any idea as to how I were to go about fixing this?

```
<span id="loginform">
    <input type="text" name="login" class="LFORM" placeholder="USERNAME" />
    <input type="password" name="password" class="LFORM" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
    <button id="LB" type="button" style="font-size: 1.4vh;">OK!</button><br />
    <a href="" id="CALINK" style="font-size:1.4vh;">Create account</a>
    <a href="" id="FLLINK" style="font-size:1.4vh;">Forgot login?</a>
</span>

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     font-size: 1.4vh;
}
#loginform {
     float: right;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     right: 1.5vh;
}
#CALINK {
     float:left;
     font-family:my_fat_font;
}
#FLLINK {
     float:right;
     font-family:my_fat_font;
}
#LB {
     border-radius: 0.4vh;
     font-family: my_fat_font;
     color: #ffffff;
     background: #ff9f2d;
     padding: 0.2vh 0.8vh 0.2vh 0.8vh;
     text-decoration: none;
     border: none;
     height: 2vh;
     margin-left: .5vh;
     margin-right: 0px;
     border: 0;
}
#LB:hover {
     background: #3e4188;
     text-decoration: none;
} 
.LFORM {
     width: 10vh;
     height: 1.8vh;
     border-radius: .3vh;
     border: none;
     padding-left: .6vh;
}
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: transparent;
}
#loginform a:hover {
     color: #ff9f2d;
     text-decoration:underline;  
}
#loginform a {
     color: #ff9f2d;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I can't really see what's wrong.  The viewport height _isn't_ changing, just how things are rendered within it.  [Viewport (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewport)

Comment: Well then I might have a wrong idea as to how the "vh" works tbh. In my opinion it would be rendered to the exact same positions.

Comment: The viewport is supposed to represent the physical space of the display.  Zoom doesn't change the physical space of the display, rather changing the contents of the display.  Think of it as looking at something through a magnifying glass.  It doesn't actually change the size of the physical object, just the size at which it's being displayed.

Comment: So is there any other reasonable way of achieving this?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TnY3L/5/

Answer (score 11):

The `vh` and `vw` units are a measurement relative to the viewport size. `1vh` is 1% of the current viewport height, so `100vh` is always 100% height. No matter how much you zoom in and out, the viewport is still the same size.

When you zoom in, you scale up the entire document (but not the viewport). It's logical that the space between elements increases as you zoom in the page, if that space is not defined in viewport units as well. Because the other elements don't increase it takes the document out of proportions.

If you want to create elements that scale as you zoom in, try using the `rem` unit. This is relative to the body's font size, so as you zoom the page in every value expressed in `rem` will scale accordingly.

Comment: if you take a div, give it `200px` width and zoom in, will it scale? If yes, your explanation is wrong.

Comment: IF you apply zoom to body for example, 0.8, 100vh won't scale all the way. If screen height is 1000px, 1vh will be 10px and it won't compensate for zoom

Answer (score 10):

`vh` and `vw` properties are bound to the the viewport size.

Many browsers (e.g. Chrome) behave in a way that when a browser is zoomed by user's action using browser's built-in zoom functionality `vh` and `vw` values are changed considerably.

But if you use css `zoom` property `vh` and `vw` remain the same.

If you need to take over this limitation you can set CSS variable according to your zoom level in CSS.

```
html {
    zoom: 90%; /* zoom your page to 90% */
}

:root {
    --zoom: 0.9; /* set the variable saying what the current zoom is */
}
```

And when using `vh` and `vw` units calculate it like this:

```
width: calc(100vw / var(--zoom));
```