# CSS vw doesn't resize header when website is zoomed out/in but pixels do

Tags: html, css, viewport, pixel, viewport-units

I'm trying to make a responsive webpage, and when I use font-size: #vw; for my header, the font-size doesn't adjust when I zoom in/out. However, when I use font-size: #px; instead, the header will naturally adjust. What am I doing wrong here?

I originally used pixels, but after learning viewport width naturally adjusts text/images to the size of the website, I changed pixels to vw. This is where the problems started to occur.

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

h1 {
    color: crimson;
    font-size: 5vw;
    margin-left: 10vw;
}
span {
    color: navy;
}
</style>

<body>
<!---Title--->
<h1 style="font-family:Franklin Gothic; display: inline;"><span>Fact</span>Judge</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the header to adjust according to what position the website is in when using vw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layout using vh does not scale with zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863724/layout-using-vh-does-not-scale-with-zoom)

Comment: vw work on window width and not window height changing. the code work. or you can explain more if i don't get it :)